# Google plus images style inside the Datalist with fixed height

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am creating a `DataList` with horizontal and vertical images in my `Asp.net` application.I want to fix the height of the images like Google Images search results and also the hover effect of images caption.

[image]

My code is

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="4"
        CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="20">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table class="item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="header">
                        <span class="name">
                            <%# Eval("ItemCode") %></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="body">

                          <a target="_blank" href="#">

               <img class="image"  src="/IMAGES/ThumbNail/<%#Eval("ImageFile")%>" /> </a>  
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="footer" align="center" style="display:none;">

                        <input type="hidden" class="is_used" value="0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Using `CSS` is enough to do that or use of 'Jquery' for that.Please help.

Comment: Regarding to your question about hover state. https://jsfiddle.net/mc98t9ca/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just give the `img`s fixed height with the `auto` for `width`:

```
img{  height: 200px; width: auto }
```

Doing so, you almost have the desired output, buf the exact thing as google images page is wanted, u may use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: ITs because u should manage it to fit ur own needs. If the simple answer is ok, just remove the `table` and simply float `img`s with the provided `css`. otherwise google for `flexbox`

Comment: Okay got it but what about hover effect ...I did't create hover effect for images yet with flexible widths

Comment: In simple way, I want to also display the image title on the particular image   @Trix

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=img+title+hover+overlay) has been invented

Comment: Wow Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Gitz Where in the html would that image title be? In it's own element or in img alt-attribute?

Comment: No not in img-alt attribute,Its separate @localZero